# Как работает подключение connect?

Tags: c++

Как устроена функция `connect`? Как лучше реализовать, стоит ли подключать 2 или 10 соединений с разными серверами. Что будет, если подключений больше 3 соединений к клиенту? Как вы реализовали восстановление подключения?

Пример:

Клиент:

```
if (connect(connectSocket[i], AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   break;
}
```

Сервер:

```
if (select(numSocket, &SockSet, 0, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `connect` запускает процесс трехстороннего квитирования - она командует TCP-стеку клиента отправить первый пакет `SYN`.

Дополнительные соединения, в теории, могут работать быстрее и утилизировать большую полосу пропускания, чем одно соединение. Это доказывается опытом существования в 90е-нулевые программ-качалок типа Download Master, которые качали один файл с сервера в несколько потоков - это позволяло забить модем на 48800 полностью. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расплатой за это будет усложнение управляющей логики и рост накладных расходов со стороны операционки на обслуживание всего этого балагана.

Восстановление соединения делается так - регулярно отсылается проверочный пакет, на который сервер должен отправить подтверждение. Если в течении заданного времени подтверждения не приходит, соединение рвется и устанавливется заново.

При любой ошибке чтения либо записи в сокет соединение устанавливается заново.

Почитайте уже учебник:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Книжку почитаю, но я бы хотел краткий ответ подводных камне, от опытного человека по сетям услышать.

Comment: Вам не следует беспокоится о таком. Операционные системы сами обрабатывают такие случаи а вам только возвращают коды состояния и/или данные.

Comment: @MrBin - вы категорически заблуждаетесь. В приведенном мной учебнике показан случай из практики, в котором программа узнает об отвале сервера через 2 часа после его падения. То есть да, механизм контроля в ОС есть, но он предназначен для очистки соединений в аварийных случаях и не предназначен для оперативного контроля за состоянием соединения. Если программа только читает сокет, она получит сообщение об ошибке спустя ооо-чень долгое время.

Comment: @gbg, Не думаю, что вы сможете прочитать что-либо из сокета, который был закрыт 2 часа назад. И я не имел ввиду, что вся обработка будет на стороне операционной системы.

Comment: Прочитайте учебник, сделайте лабораторную, потом "не думайте". Так как сервер при отвале ничего в сокет не пишет, клиент, который все время читает сокет, никак не узнает, что процесс сервера отвалился, он узнает об этом, только при попытке записи в сокет.

Написав вот это "Операционные системы сами обрабатывают такие случаи а вам только возвращают коды состояния и/или данные" что вы в таком случае имели в виду? Потрудитесь объяснить.

Comment: @gbg,  2 часа для TCP по умолчанию, вообще же -- [use the SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO socket options to set timeouts for any socket operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182564/7286264)

Comment: @gdb, писал портянку, а сайт не хочет добавлять... Короче, не приход данных за 2 часа по TCP - это expected, который должен обрабатывать программист. Unexpected - операция завершилась неудачей (Нет подтверждения получения по таймауту, недоступность хоста и тд и та). А подводные камни - это unexpected. Операционная система нормально справляется с unexpected.

Comment: @gdb, разработчик должен знать такие детали реализации. Но, имхо, это не подводные камни, о которых спрашилось выше.

Comment: А разве такие программы как Download Master не по UDP работают?
Им же не обязательно какие данные принимать, главное сгруппировать их в правильном порядке.

Comment: Нет, они работают по HTTP/HTTPS/FTP, которые работают поверх TCP.

Comment: Интересно а как примерно работает Download Master? Есть примеры как он создает эти потоки?

Comment: @zip - чтобы понять, как он работает, достаточно посмотреть на его логи. Файл режется на равные куски по числу потоков. Когда любой из потоков заканчивается, берется самый длинный недокачанный участок и делится пополам - с этой самой середины начинает качать освободившийся поток.

Comment: А как он разрезает файл на куски, разве так можно?
И как сервер передает разрезанные куски?

Comment: @zip, в данном случае абсолютно не важно в каком порядке передавать данные из файла. "Разрезать на куски" - это не делать новые файлы, а просто данные по смещению от начала. Я не знаю как именно работает Download Manager, но предполагаю, что в начале каждый поток сообщает смещение, с которого он начнет передавать данные.

Comment: @MrBin А где модно почитать про смещения? Интересно узнать вдруг пригодиться.

Comment: @zip, тут не в моде дело, а в необходимости. Смещение в файле - это тоже абстрактное определение. Но оно описывает очень простую сущность - количество байт от начала файла. Это просто начало какого-то интервала, он может быть ограничен любой другой сущностью на ваш выбор (Следующим смещением, константой, каким-либо символом), а может и нет. К сожалению ссылки дать не могу. Разве что Википедия предлагает.

Comment: Хорошо сам тогда попробую разобраться